# VCE in pnp transistor

Tags: bjt

If VCE is negative in a PNP transistor does that mean that it is in saturation? Note: not given the saturation value.

This is related to a homework question.

Thanks

Comment: Do you actually mean \$V_{CE}\$? Or maybe \$V_{CB}\$??

Answer (score 5):

V<sub>CE</sub> = -V<sub>EC</sub>

For PNP transistors, some datasheets actually use V<sub>EC</sub> (or similar identifiers), most datasheets use negative values.

A negative V<sub>CE</sub>, meaning V<sub>C</sub> - V<sub>E</sub> < 0 is common for a PNP transistor in normal use. Take a look at a common emitter for both NPN and PNP:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSoqP5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Take a result from NPN transistor analysis, e.g.:  for a NPN transistor to be in forward-active mode, we must have:

$$V_{BE} > 0$$

$$V_{CB} > 0$$

To get the correct result for PNP transistors, simply (1) reverse the polarity of all voltage variables, i.e., \$V_{CE} \rightarrow V_{EC}\$ and (2) reverse the direction of all current variables.

Thus, for a PNP transistor to be in forward-active mode, we must have

$$V_{EB} > 0$$

$$V_{BC} > 0$$

Since \$V_{EC} = V_{EB} + V_{BC}\$, we have that, for a PNP transistor, \$V_{EC} > 0\$ when the transistor is active.

Or, in other words, \$V_{CE} < 0\$ for a PNP transistor does not imply it is in saturation.